# Jquery plugin: accessing element attributes inner the settings init

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to access a data attribute ('maxselection') of several html elements while attaching them to a jquery plugin :

```
$(".select2").select2({ // several html elements
    maximumSelectionSize: $(this).data('maxselection')
});
```

That doesn't work.

How can you reach the element attributes in this specific scope ?

*btw: select2 is a dropdown enhancer, a fork of chosen*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not the selected element(s) inside of the object literal definition. Something like this would work:

```
$(".select2").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.select2({
        maximumSelectionSize: $this.data('maxselection');
    });
});
```